# My DataGridView is not changing its color?

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors

This is my code, it should show 2015 years data in a red color and 2016s in green. but is not working?

[image]

```
private void changecolor()
{    
     foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dgvExpense.Rows)
     {
         DateTime dates = (DateTime)rows.Cells[2].Value;

         if (dates.Year == 2015)
         {
             rows.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
         }
         else if (dates.Year == 2016)
         {
             rows.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
         }  
     }
}
```

Comment: How do you call this `changecolor` method? And it shouldn't be `Cells[3]` instead?

Comment: Thank you a lot bro, I did not called it,what is why it was not worked. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Because the index starts with 0 you should be using `Cells[3]`.
Your code will look like this:

```
private void changecolor()
{    
     foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dgvExpense.Rows)
     {
         DateTime dates = (DateTime)rows.Cells[3].Value;

         if (dates.Year == 2015))
             rows.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
         else if (dates.Year == 2016)
             rows.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
     }
}
```

Comment: Even it would start `1` as a starting index, it will be `Cells[4]` not `Cells[2]` :)